# Why tibble is showing local time after reading feather file

Tags: r, feather

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamps, like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')]})
```

I write it to a feather file with `df.to_feather('a.feather')`, and read it back in R with `df <- arrow::read_feather('a.feather')`.

When I display it, I see

```
A tibble: 1 × 1 a
<dttm>
2020-01-01 01:00:00
```

Where did the `01:00:00` come from? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it seems that R or arrow is paying attention to some kind of global time zone variable. So the above behaviour can be fixed by adding

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
```

in the beggining.

Inspired by this: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/timestamps.html